# Как определить касание спрайтов в canvas, чтобы прозрачный фон не считался?

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas

Я написал функцию, которая по координатам и размерам определяет, касаются ли две картинки в canvas друг друга.

```
function (sprite1, sprite2) {
    return
    sprite1.x + sprite1.width >= sprit2e.x &&
    sprite1.x <= sprite2.x + sprite2.width &&
    sprite1.y + sprite1.height >= sprite2.y &&
    sprite1.y <= sprite2.y + sprite2.height;
}
```

Но проблема в том, что если две картинки с прозрачным фоном касаются только фоном, функция также определяет касание. Я хочу чтобы касание считалось только если касаются какие-то цвета картинок, кроме прозрачного.

Пример касания только прозрачным фоном:

[image: Пример]

Пожалуйста, помогите!!!

Comment: https://docplayer.ru/79921882-Algoritmy-obnaruzheniya-kolliziy-ploskih-dvumernyh-obektov-proizvolnoy-formy.html

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Я посмотрел, не всё понятно. Можете написать как называется библиотека в JavaScript, если такая есть, или функцию?